# Android Studio unable to resolve dependencies from mavenCentral() since 0.5.5

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I have a gradle project containing several different java libraries, android libraries, and a single android application. On Android Studio 0.5.4 the project builds just fine. However, when I try to import the project using any of Android Studio versions 0.5.5 through 0.5.8 (the latest as of this writing), the build fails with this error

```
Error: A problem occurred configuring project 'my-libraries:an-android-library'.
    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':my-libraries:an-android-library:_debugCompile'.
       > Could not find com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1.
        Required by:
          <a bunch of my libraries>

       <repeat with more dependencies from maven central>
```

What I find most interesting about this situation is that the project builds just fine using gradle from the command line (I use the gradle wrapper version 1.11 from command line and in Android Studio). It also doesn't seem to fail on dependencies from the support libraries.

The project has three tiers and common logic is extracted out into different build files (which is to say that I'd prefer to avoid posting all of the build logic if possible). I'm hoping that the fact that it builds fine on command line but not in Android Studio rings a bell for someone.

Comment: Anything in the event log, by any chance? If not, my observations about the differences between command-line and Android Studio are that the working directory is different between those two, and it might handle network proxies differently. I doubt either of those two suggestions are helpful. I wish you could add an --info or --stacktrace to the Android Studio command line passed to Gradle, but I don't think you can.

Comment: @scott, the event log is pretty clean: Gradle invocation completed successfully with 2 error(s) in 2 sec. Actually, I was able to add command line options in Preferences > Compiler > Gradle. However, the root cause of the error is `org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1`, which doesn't give us a lot of new information. Adding the `--offline` option didn't help either.

Comment: You're using mavenCentral, right? Any chance you have Preferences > Gradle > Offline work set?

Comment: @scott, correct, I'm using mavenCentral, and no, I do not have have the "Offline work" option set. I tried setting it just for fun, and it gives the message "Unresolved Dependencies: Unresolved dependencies detected while building project in offline mode. Please disable offline mode and try again."

Comment: @JustusCustos are u able come over this problem